# Is it possible to name a jquery selector the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if i had a variable in javascript

```
 var nombre;
 onclick="nombre='someValue'"
```

and somewhere along in my code this javascript variable's value is changed like above, could I set the value of that variable to be the class name in the jquery selector so it would be like

```
$('.someValue').show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
$('.' + nombre).show();
```

This assumes that your variable `nombre` has such scope that it is available in your jQuery code too.